Issue enable monetization for two consumer with the same API using WSO2
I have enabled Monetization for APIs in WSO2 APIM 4.2 ,but the issue is that i have to create for each Subscriber a new APIs because each Monetized API have a specific ConnectID related to Client .
How to handle this issue, does monetization should be enabled with APIs or with API Products .
I tried to enable monetization by API and it can be consumed by many subscriber  without create Monetized API for each Consumer.
